# Why XCode copies resources to iDevice each time, even when they still not changed?

Tags: iphone, xcode, resources, copy

I only change source code. And when I build it into device (iPod Touch 4 gen), XCode copies resources. As I know, XCode must recognize that resources were not changed and skip copy phase.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of resources? XCode will leave your files in your document folder untouched, but resources like images etc. which are not in the users documents folder are overwritten every time you make a new build.

What is exactly copied every time?

Comment: There is no problems with documents directory. I have a lot of files (mostly png images) attached within folder reference to my project. When installing the app on device I watch progress of copying each file. So I'm looking for some optimization to skip this when resources don't change.